# More than 5 custom variables across multiple websites using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

We have multiple websites using the same Google Analytics account number so we can track visitors across multiple websites. One of these websites has set 5 custom variables. We want to introduce a new custom variable to track logged in users for our single sign-on (SSO) system to find out what parts of which website they are accessing.

Is this possible or is it a case that all the custom variables have been used up by 1 of the sites?

Comment: What level are the custom variables set at?   Google Analytics allows custom variables to be set at the page level, the session level, and the user level.   The limits for custom variables depend on which level you are setting these.

Comment: 6 at visitor level. 4 at session. I didn't set this up but appears to have answered my own question.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own question. Please do so, so that we can all benefit!

Comment: Was this finally resolved? Can the OP confirm or is there no solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If all of the sites are sharing the same Google Analytics account number (same property), you are allowed five custom variable slots. From your response around the level the custom variables are set at, you state that you have 6 CVs at visitor-level and 4 CVs at session-level. So I take it that you are using multiple properties. Have your thought about using Universal Analytics? In doing so, you'll have access to 20 Custom dimensions - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/features/customdimsmets

Answer (score 1):

You can set as many as you want, just that you have to be careful when they might overwrite each other. You can refer to the link below for more information on the order of precedence.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables?csw=1